# running bash script from a different directory in php

Tags: php, bash

I'm trying in my website to run a bash script take located in a different folder to where i call the script.
My script is located in

```
~/var/www/html/scripts/try.sh
```

and the page that call him is in:

```
~/var/www/html/pages/try.php
```

the try.php goes like this :

```
<? php
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('../scripts/');
$output = shell_exec('./try.sh');
chdir($old_path);
?>
```

and try.sh is :

```
echo 1 > working.txt
```

for both of them i gave chmod 755
any idea why it's not working ? i have tried couple of ways in the php and no success 
please help me :(
Thank you very much for getting here

Comment: How exactly it is not working? What happens?

Comment: Noting , i just did a simple script to check if it works and make a new file (working.txt) but the file is not created - there for the script didn't run

Comment: Did PHP put any error message in the webserver logs? Also put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of your php script to see all warnings and notices in the logfile.

Comment: IP - - [10/Jul/2015:15:32:57 -0400] "GET /scripts/try.php HTTP/1.1" 500 206 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) $

Comment: HTTP `500` is internal server error. Do you have `.htaccess` file somewhere? Put simple `echo "test";` in the beginning of php script to see if it gets executed at all or not...

Comment: i put a echo at the start and one in the end,  i can see the first one, but not the second one

Comment: you may be in `safe` mode, deprecated since 5.3.